What is the chance of numbers created from numbers 1 to 5 being divisible by 4.
As a five-year-old, I am unable to understand the answer to this being anything other than 24 out of 120 (1/5), but somehow 16, 36 and 48 are valid endings. Can someone make an arguement to support this please?
Posted by itversity on YouTube.

3 days ago Quiz Answer Reveal! Thank you to everyone who participated in our recent quiz! Let's see how you did:
Question: The digits 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are arranged to form a number. What is the probability that the number is divisible by 4?
Correct Answer: 7/20
Explanation: The probability is 7/20. Total arrangements = 5! = 120. Valid endings divisible by 4 = {12, 24, 32, 52, 16, 36, 48). Each ending allows 3! = 6 arrangements of remaining digits. Total favorable outcomes = 7 x 6 = 42. Probability = 42/120 = 7/20


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Richard Can you please what exactly you find confusing and why? Are you trying to understand why a number ending in 16 is a multiple of 4? What exactly makes you think that such a number would not be a multiple of 4? Do you understand that the number 16 itself is a multiple of 4?

Are you familiar with the fact that a number is divisible by 4 if its last two digits are divisible by 4?

The answer $7/20$ is very strange. How can we consider $16$ or $36$ or $48$, when we say that the available digits are ${1,2,3,4,5}$ ;$ 4/20$  ( or $24/120$ but I don't like it) is the correct answwer.

The valid endings (considering that we have the digits $1,2 \cdots 5$)  are $\{12, 24, 32, 52\}$.
Then we have $4 \times 3! = 24$ valid permutations.
Then, it seems you are right, and the quoted answer is wrong.
